# Android apps won't connect over school WiFi

Tags: applications, wi-fi, internet

I have several apps that won't connect even though I connected to WiFi. Google Chrome and browser work fine, but other apps say can't connect to the server or needs an internet connection. When I'm at home, it works fine.

Comment: Most likely those apps want to connect to sites which are blocked by the school's firewall. Just a wild guess – but the most obvious possibility.

Answer (score 0):

My school uses a similar system, probably the same actually.  What I think it is, is either **Deep Packet Inspection** or your **Firewall**.

I am almost positive, all I know is that your school blocks the applications somehow (it could also just block the website or server the app uses).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on which apps you are talking about.

Your school may be blocking certain ports. Check with the app dev to see which ports they use. This may be available through an FAQ on their site (which may include additional hints).

Your school may also have some type of content filtering solution in place. At my institution, our content filtering service is often blocking perfectly legitimate content.

Lastly, check with your school's network administrator. If it's appropriate content, they'll probably be willing to help open it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in college and in my case, there is a proxy. This is common, and it's sometimes a good thing because it protects the people behind it. In this case, you may need to contact your network admin and ask how to access the network properly.

If the proxy has no authentication, it's just a little setup, but if not, you may need to use some app to get authenticated. If this is the case you can try ProxyDroid (it need root access) from [here](https://es.apkhere.com/app/org.proxydroid) or PlayStore, or ProxyAuth from [here](https://apkpure.com/es/proxyauth-for-android/in.silverstonelabs.proxyauth) on PlayStore.

Sorry if this is not the problem, but it was in my case.